# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'patient_col'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I've the code as following

```
def check_for_leakage(df1, df2, patient_col):

    df1_patients_unique = set(df1.patient_col.unique())
    df2_patients_unique = set(df2.patient_col.unique())
    patients_in_both_groups = list(df1_patients_unique.intersection(df2_patients_unique))
    leakage = len(patients_in_both_groups) > 0 # boolean (true if there is at least 1 patient in both groups)

    return leakage
```

and when i run

```
# test
print("test case 1")
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'patient_id': [0, 1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patient_id': [2, 3, 4]})
print("df1")
print(df1)
print("df2")
print(df2)
print(f"leakage output: {check_for_leakage(df1, df2, 'patient_id')}")
```

I get the following error :

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'patient_col'

i've tried several things but I can't understand how to solve this issue. I also can't find ant appropriate answers to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the column name in brackets:

```
    df1_patients_unique = set(df1[patient_col].unique())
    df2_patients_unique = set(df2[patient_col].unique())
```

The notation with df1.column only works with actual column names. You can't enter a variable here.

Comment: Thanks, I was putting ' ' inside brackets too.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change in the function:

```
def check_for_leakage(df1, df2, patient_col):

    df1_patients_unique = set(df1[patient_col].unique())
    df2_patients_unique = set(df2[patient_col].unique())
    patients_in_both_groups = list(df1_patients_unique.intersection(df2_patients_unique))
    leakage = len(patients_in_both_groups) > 0 # boolean (true if there is at least 1 patient in both groups)

    return leakage

print("test case 1")
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'patient_id': [0, 1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patient_id': [2, 3, 4]})
print("df1")
print(df1)
print("df2")
print(df2)
print(f"leakage output: {check_for_leakage(df1, df2, 'patient_id')}")

Output:
test case 1
df1
   patient_id
0           0
1           1
2           2
df2
   patient_id
0           2
1           3
2           4
leakage output: True
```